# Are these two "Code Snippets"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, countability

people use "Code Snippet" or "Code Snippets" everywhere.

"[Code Snippet](https://dev.to/matthewbrophy/code-snippets---a-beginners-guide-p4d)" is a term used to describe a small portion of re-usable source code, machine code, or text.

following lines of code comes from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snippet_(programming)) (denote as snippet_1)

```
temp = x
x = y
y = temp
```

and another (denote as snippet_1)

```
Hello {%first_name%} {%last_name%}
```

it seems that "Code Snippet" is a countable noun. so, snippet_1 and snippet_2 are two "Code Snippets"?

do I use this term correctly?

Comment: The title you've given your question doesn't seem to match the question itself. Are you asking whether "code snippet" is a countable noun, or whether the example you have posted is actually a code snippet? The answer to the first question is "yes"; I have no idea what the answer to the second question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "code snippet" is a countable noun, so it is perfectly correct to use it as you have. For example:

> The following two code snippets illustrate the limitations of the direct approach.

I don't see any errors in your understanding or usage in the question.